# Binding same data to multiple dropdownlists using foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

We have 10 dropdowns and data should bind from SQL Server to dropdowns using foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void bindDropdowns(DataSet ds)
      {
       foreach (Control control in form1.Controls)
            {
             if ((control.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList)))
                   {
                        ((DropDownList)(control)).DataTextField = "InformationReview";
                        ((DropDownList)(control)).DataValueField="InformationReviewID";
                        ((DropDownList)(control)).DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        ((DropDownList)(control)).DataBind();
                        ((DropDownList)(control)).Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select--", "0"));
                    }
      }}
```

Comment: Best usage of `&nbsp;` ever.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you **(a)** don't need *any* of those messy `<br/>` and `&nbsp;` elements, and **(b)** your code is properly syntax-highlighted ......